# How can I sort a nested dict by multiple criteria for values and keys?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a nested dict in Python that I want to sort.

In the first step I want it to be sorted by "points".
If all the "points" are equal, use "wins".
If "points" and "wins" are equal, it should be sorted by the team names like "Brazil", "Morocco", etc.

My dict is

```
list_of_team = {
    "Brazil": {"wins": 1, "loses": 1, "draws": 1, "goal difference": 0, "points": 4},
    "Spain": {"wins": 1, "loses": 1, "draws": 1, "goal difference": 0, "points": 4},
    "Portugal": {"wins": 1, "loses": 1, "draws": 1, "goal difference": 0, "points": 4},
    "Morocco": {"wins": 1, "loses": 1, "draws": 1, "goal difference": 0, "points": 4}
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
Brazil  wins:1 , loses:1 , draws:1 , goal difference:0 , points:4

Morocco  wins:1 , loses:1 , draws:1 , goal difference:0 , points:4 

Portugal  wins:1 , loses:1 , draws:1 , goal difference:0 , points:4

Spain  wins:1 , loses:1 , draws:1 , goal difference:0 , points:4
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] to provide a more realistic example, where some of the values for points and wins are not equal, just so it's clear how the output should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted(list_of_team, key= lambda x : list_of_team[x].get("points"))`

Comment: It doesn't answer the rest of the question, namely sorting by wins if points are equal, and by team names if both points and wins are equal.